# Why doesn't Excel show the data points and values on this geographic map chart of US counties within a state?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, office365

I have these (arbitrary) data points in Excel, and I've selected the Geography type for each of the counties in the US state of Massachusetts.

[image: data]

I inserted a map chart, which displays the following map:

[image: map of counties within US state]

I clicked Add Chart Element, Data Labels, and then used these options, **but the values still don't show up on the map itself.**

[image: data label options]

**How do I get these values to appear on the map?** I don't want a legend; I want each value to appear within the shape of the county on the map. According to [this article](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-the-geography-data-type-to-quickly-add-a-map-chart-in-excel/), what I did above should work, I think.

Comment: Even stranger, when I try to recreate the situation, I only get one data label. It's very tiny and it's in Nantucket so it's hidden by the "powered by bing" message. I was able to see it if I made the map very large and zoomed in. Even more frustrating, I tried it with Kentucky counties like in the example article you linked and it worked perfectly. I tried Michigan, too, in case states split by water causes a problem but it worked fine there, too.

Comment: Thank you for checking that. Even if it was missing data in the Bing Maps API, you'd think the data _values_ would at least show up, since that's data I'm entering directly. If I mouse over each county, the tool tip shows the county name, value, etc. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with one of the counties that prevents the map to show the labels. When Nantucket is selected the labels disappear. When it is not, they are shown normally. See image below.

Why does the issue occur only for Nantucket? Might be because it not shown on the map as when testing with only 2-3 counties close to the ocean and Nantucket, it was still not displayed on the map. But, I cannot ascertain it 100%.

[image]

Comment: Possibly related: [Bing doesn't seem to think](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvl6M.png) that Nantucket is a county in Massachusetts. Possibly also related: The region in that chart map for Nantucket [doesn't match the actual map of the area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47Krr.gif). For one, it seems to think it's two regions instead of just one.

Comment: Very strange all around, but this did fix the problem. Thank you both.